# Установка пакета php53u-xml (CentOS)

Tags: php, xml, centos

Как мне установить пакет `php53u-xml` (*CentOS*)?

Есть ли еще какой-то репозиторий, где этот пакет  доступен?

Информация об одном из установленных оттуда пакетов:

```
[root@us03659 ~]# rpm -qi php53u-5.3.15-1.ius.el5
Name        : php53u                       Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 5.3.15                            Vendor: IUS Community Project
Release     : 1.ius.el5                     Build Date: Mon 23 Jul 2012 05:35:25 PM EEST
Install Date: Mon 10 Sep 2012 06:28:26 PM EEST      Build Host: 339180-build01.rpmdev.rackspace.com
Group       : Development/Languages         Source RPM: php53u-5.3.15-1.ius.el5.src.rpm
Size        : 4411742                          License: The PHP License v3.01
Signature   : DSA/SHA1, Thu 09 Aug 2012 06:08:41 AM EEST, Key ID da221cdf9cd4953f
URL         : http://www.php.net/
Summary     : The PHP HTML-embedded scripting language. (PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor)
Description :
PHP is an HTML-embedded scripting language. PHP attempts to make it
easy for developers to write dynamically generated webpages. PHP also
offers built-in database integration for several commercial and
non-commercial database management systems, so writing a
database-enabled webpage with PHP is fairly simple. The most common
use of PHP coding is probably as a replacement for CGI scripts.

The php package contains the module which adds support for the PHP
language to Apache HTTP Server.
```

p.s. этот же вопрос на [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/708192/how-can-i-install-php53u-xml-package-centos).

Comment: вероятно, точно так же, как вы установили все остальные пакеты, название которых начинается с `php53u`. ведь это явно лишь «кусочек» от разбитой на пакеты кодовой базы определённой сборки `php`. если у вас не получается описанная процедура, пожалуйста, так и напишите в вопросе, изложив и подробности: откуда взяты остальные пакеты, почему не удаётся установить названный и т.д.

Comment: Я устанавливал остальные пакеты где-то 2 года назад. Теперь мне нужно доустановить еще один пакет, но пакеты php53u-* уже не доступны. Апгрейд php до версии 5.5 или 5.6 я сделать не могу

Comment: откуда вы их устанавливали?

Comment: С помощью команды yum install php53u*
Если сейчас ввести команду yum install php53u-xml, то выводит
No package php53u-xml available.

Comment: из какого репозитория это устанавливалось?
если из дистрибутивного, то, вероятно, версия вашего дистрибутива уже ушла «в архив».
посмотрите, что выводит
`rpm -qi имя.пакета`
для установленных пакетов, начинающихся с `php53u`. получить их список можно, например, так:
   `rpm -qa | grep ^php53u`

Comment: Устанавливалось из  дистрибутивного репозитория. Команда rpm -qi имя.пакета выводит стандартную информацию о пакетах (http://pixs.ru/showimage/1212jpg_8786452_18147460.jpg).

Comment: нет, это не репозиторный пакет. уточняю: не из репозитория дистрибутива — смотрите поле vendor. а в чём была особенность **именно этой** сборки? почему вы поставили **именно её**? спрашиваю для того, чтобы выработать подходящий вариант решения проблемы.

Comment: Я не знаю в чем особенность этой сборки. Если просто ввести команду yum install php-xml, то возникает ошибка совместимости с пакетом php-common. Вот аналогичная проблема, но те решения что там приводятся мне не помогли (http://serverfault.com/questions/391772)

Comment: ну, место архива я уже нашёл (по имени из поля vendor). чтобы другим людям ваш вопрос смог быть полезен, дополните его, пожалуйста (здесь или на serverfault) **текстовым** выводом для одного из пакетов: `rpm -qi один.из.тех.пакетов` (первый, который на скриншоте, пойдёт). отредактировать вопрос можно, нажава кнопку [edit].

Comment: если мой ответ помог решить проблему, отметьте его, пожалуйста, принятым (галочка слева от ответа).

Comment: Спасибо за пакеты! Еще подскажите, пожалуйста, как подключить этот репозиторий (i386)

Comment: подключать там нечего — отсутствуют файлы с репозиторной мета-информацией. там просто «свалка» rpm-файлов. как установить — я написал в обновлении к ответу. p.s. намекаю: на serverfault тоже можно отметить ответ принятым.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

по имени вендора с приложенного скриншота определил местонахождение архива:

```
https://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/archive/Redhat/5/
```

исходя из точного номера версии `5.3.15-1`, вам нужен один из этих пакетов (32- или 64-битный):

```
https://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/archive/Redhat/5/i386/php53u-xml-5.3.15-1.ius.el5.i386.rpm
https://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/archive/Redhat/5/x86_64/php53u-xml-5.3.15-1.ius.el5.x86_64.rpm
```

скачайте нужный файл и установите в обход пакетного менеджера:

```
# rpm -ivh /путь/к/скачанному/пакету.rpm
```